# Running HUnit tests with Hspec

Tags: haskell, hunit, hspec

I want to run HUnit tests inside a spec:

```hs
module SHCSpec (spec)
    where

import Test.Hspec
import Test.Hspec.Contrib.HUnit
import Test.HUnit

import SHC.Types
import SHC.Lix


spec :: Spec
spec = do
    fromHUnitTest ("SHC.Lix" ~: "toHit" ~:
        [ Irrelevant @=? toHit []
        , None       @=? toHit [False]
        , None       @=? toHit [False, False]
        , Partial    @=? toHit [False, True]
        , Partial    @=? toHit [True, False]
        , Partial    @=? toHit [False, False, True]
        , Partial    @=? toHit [False, True, False]
        , Partial    @=? toHit [True, False, False]
        , Full       @=? toHit [True]
        , Full       @=? toHit [True, True]
        ])
```

The above code works, but it produces this ugly output:

```
SHC
  SHC.Lix
    toHit
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
      <unlabeled>
```

Is it possible to attach the label `toHit` to every test case? Something like this:

```
SHC
  SHC.Lix
    toHit
    toHit
    toHit
    toHit
    toHit
    toHit
    toHit
    toHit
    toHit
    toHit
```

Even better would be to append a number to each `toHit` case. I messed with `TestList` and `map TestLabel` to no avail.

Comment: What about `map ("toHit" ~:)`? I haven't tested it but it seems like it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about attaching labels to all the tests with a function like:

```
label ts =
  [ show i ~: t | (i,t) <- zip [(1::Int)..] ts ]
```

Just prefix your list of tests with a call to `label`:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
    fromHUnitTest ("SHC.Lix" ~: "toHit" ~:
        label
        [ Irrelevant @=? toHit []
        , None       @=? toHit [False]
        ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I did something very similar to this one!